# Can a Chemical's Opacity be Deduced Mathematically?

Tags: optics, mathematics, physical-chemistry

all. I have tried Googling but have had no luck. My question is simple (although, I presume the answer is not): If one knows the chemical structure of, well, a chemical, could its optical properties (such as transparency) be mathematically derived from this information alone? Perhaps I'm naive for thinking so, but I would imagine it's possible, given the electron count and three-dimensional structure of the compound.

I ask this on the Physics Stack Exchange because I feel like it falls into the Optics/Physical-Side-of-Physical-Chemistry realm than into pure Chemistry territory.

If I need to elaborate some more, please feel free to comment and let me know. Likewise, if needed, please pardon any idiocy.

Comment: "In theory, theory and practice are the same. In practice, they are not." -- AlbertEinstein and "In theory there is no difference between theory and practice. In practice there is."
-- YogiBerra. Now, while it is likely that at least one of these quotes is falsely attributed, they highlight the reality of your problem: in theory you can derive all optical properties of a material from first principles, in practice an experiment would almost always show you the limitations of your knowledge about the substance, rather than give you the correct answer for practical purposes.

Answer (score 1):

Light incident on an object can be transmitted or reflected/scattered. (It can also be absorbed and lead to photoionization/thermal effects, but that is perhaps not so relevant for the discussion here).

Depending on the composition of the material, i.e., the variety of atoms, their electronic structure, and also their arrangement, different optical frequencies would behave differently. Some frequencies may simply transmit through. Others may be absorbed by the atom and re-emitted almost immediately (this is the basis for the reflection or scattering mechanism). Quantifying this behaviour is of course not an easy task but in principle, an exact knowledge of the chemical composition as well as the physical structure *including* surface properties (think of a polished diamond versus an uncut one) should suffice to predict its optical properties.

Comment: Just for fun, assuming I have this information about the composition's surface properties and overall physical structure, how would I go about calculating this?